# clicked event not working in textedit of pyside

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

i have a code like this in my class

```
 self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
 self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 351, 51))
 self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
 QtCore.QObject.connect(self.textEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.text_click)
 QtCore.QObject.connect(self.textEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged()"), self.text_change)
 def text_change(self):
     print "change ok"
 def text_click(self):
     print "clicked ok
```

in my code text change event is working  properly . But click event not working.
How can i detect click event in textedit widget ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is correct way. You can use `mousePressEvent`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

def text_change():
    print "change ok"
def text_click(event): # <--- NOTE: event object is passed.
    print "clicked ok "

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 351, 51))
textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
textEdit.mousePressEvent = text_click
QtCore.QObject.connect(textEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged()"), text_change)
textEdit.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

tested with PyQt 4.10.2. (Window 7, Python 2.7.5)

**UPDATE**

`mousePressEvent` also works on PyQt5.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

def text_change():
    print("change ok")
def text_click(event):
    print("clicked ok ")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 351, 51))
textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
textEdit.mousePressEvent = text_click
textEdit.textChanged.connect(text_change)
textEdit.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

tested with PyQt 5.0 (Windows 7, Python 3.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for [`QTextEdit`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html), you'll notice that it *doesn't have* a `clicked` signal.

If you would use [new style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), you'd catch such errors earlier, as you can't connect non existing signals that way, you'd get an error:

```
>>> self.textEdit.clicked.connect(...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'clicked'
```

Using [old style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html), signals are defined implicitly when they are emitted, therefore when calling `QObject.connect` there is no check if the signal really exists.

If you want `QTextEdit` to emit a `clicked` signal, you need to override one of it's mouse-event handlers and emit the signal yourself.

Old style signals will be gone in PyQt5, so you should really get used to new style signals instead.

---

*edit* - Simple example how to define a clicked signal on a class derived from `QTextEdit`:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTextEdit
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    textEdit = TextEdit()
    textEdit.clicked.connect(lambda: print('clicked'))
    textEdit.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: How to override mouse-event handlers  to emit signal?